# Get current index value in Populator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake-task

I have created a rake task to create test data using [populator](http://populator.rubyforge.org/). I need to read index of current iteration and set in one of the attribute of the model. Can anyone please tell how to read current index value in populate method?

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Erase and fill database"
  task :populate => :environment do
    require 'populator'

    Category.delete_all

    Category.populate 50 do |category|
      category.name = Populator.words(1..3).titleize
      category.index = {CURRENT_INDEX}
    end
  end
end
```

where `{CURRENT_INDEX}` should be index value of current iteration.

I tried adding index in block variable `Category.populate 50 do |category, index|` assuming ruby for each loop sysntax but didn't work.

Comment: depth is stored here: https://github.com/ryanb/populator/blob/master/lib/populator/factory.rb#L7

Comment: @apneadiving thanks for reply. I tried `category.index = @depth` not helped.

Comment: would you please explain why it is class variable?

Comment: see: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Comment: class variables starts with @@ and member(instance) variable starts with @. Here @depth starts with single @ which means it is member variable(instance).

Comment: see this paragraph: `Class Level Instance Variables`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like rubygem.org has not updated gem after [changes](https://github.com/ryanb/populator/issues/19). Here is how I fixed it.

I pointed source of gem directly to master branch.

so replaced

```
gem 'populator'
```

with

```
gem 'populator', git: "https://github.com/ryanb/populator.git"
```

in **Gemfile**

And in my rake task

```
...
Category.populate 50 do |category, index|
      category.name = Populator.words(1..3).titleize
      category.index = index
    end
...
```